# TimePicker onTimeChanged() event keeps firing as timepicker spins

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I am using a timepicker for one of my custom alert dialog and I call a method to validate the values and perform some actions when the timepicker value is changed by user.

The issue is that the onTimeChanged event keeps firing when the timepicker is spinning, and that it does not trigger as a single event when time picker stops spinning.

How to get to know *when the timepicker stops spinning*, so that I can call my method only then, and not at every value when the timepicker spins?

Here is my current code:

```
startTimePicker = (TimePicker)rootView.findViewById(R.id.timePickerStart);
startTimePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            validatemethod();//Keeps firing as the timepicker is spinning
    }
    });
```

Comment: Use onTimeSet method instead of ontimeChanged

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener.html

Comment: Can't use this as I am using a timepicker within a custom alert dialog. onTimeSet method is for TimePickerDialog and not for TimePicker View

Comment: how did you solve your issue?